# sending multiple emails with mvcmailer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, razor, mvcmailer

Im looking to use [MVCMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) to send emails using asp.net mvc 3 with razor. Also mentioned by [ScottHa](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek2MvcMailerSendsMailsWithASPNETMVCRazorViewsAndScaffolding.aspx)

It looks fairly straight forward, however i'm confused as to how I would send batch emails eg like a newsletter to a list of users.

do i create a loop around this?

```
public virtual MailMessage Welcome()
{
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage{Subject = "Welcome to MvcMailer"};

    mailMessage.To.Add("sohan39@example.com");
    ViewBag.Name = "Sohan";
    PopulateBody(mailMessage, viewName: "Welcome");

    return mailMessage;
}
```

can someone explain?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately because each email message is personalized, I can't see any other way other than looping. So just change your method to something like:

```
public virtual MailMessage Welcome(string email, string name)
{
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage{Subject = "Welcome to MvcMailer"};

    mailMessage.To.Add(email);
    ViewBag.Name = name;
    PopulateBody(mailMessage, viewName: "Welcome");

    return mailMessage;
}
```

And then call that method inside your loop and send it at the same time.

**Important Note**

You should setup your web.config to use a pickup directory rather than a SMTP server. Then get IIS to send the email from the pickup directory.

Reasoning - Because you could potentially be calling `SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage mailmessage)` any number of times - this could become rather expensive if you have to connect to a SMTP server each time to send the email.

A nice side effect of this is you also get some redundancy if the SMTP server is down or unreachable for any reason.

Comment: I'm on a shared server so i guess the pickup directory suggestion wont work?in that case is it best to just send asynchronously?

Comment: Yeah, good idea. This video may help you with that http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-send-email-asynchronously-with-aspnet. For redundancy you could possibly throw the email messages into a database and then once they are sent, mark them as sent in the database. Then create some admin tool to try and resend all the unsent emails.

Answer (score 1):

If you want different content for each email, you'll need to create individual `MailMessage` objects using a loop. If you want the same contents, then you can just add multiple recipients:

```
mailMessage.To.Add("sohan39@example.com");
mailMessage.To.Add("peter23@example.com");
```

Comment: if i surround with a loop the return will just break out after one message though right?

Comment: The loop needs to go outside of the method. Without the code that calls this method, it's hard to say - I don't know where the email is actually being sent.